# consequences of adding class files directly into an exploded deployed ear in WAS 7

Tags: java, deployment, cluster-computing, websphere-7

I would like to know what are the pros and cons, if any, of injecting or dropping java class files into an exploded ear file that is deployed in WAS 7.

When we install the packaged ear file it gets exploded into a certain temp directory and we can actually go into the folder location of the class file and replace it with our new class file and restart the server to load it.

If we are doing it for every node in WAS 7 and restarting them one by one for HA. would there be an issue.

Thanks.
Syed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another con to worry about.  If you replace the file on the node and DMGR doesn't know about it, if you do a full sync the file from the DMGR will be pushed out to the nodes.

The recommended way to do this is to properly get the new file in the EAR and do another deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You might encounter problems if the class contains annotations since application deployment caches the result of annotation scanning.  Otherwise, you might be able to get it to work, but I doubt you would get support from IBM if something breaks.  The supported mechanism for what you're trying to do is available via [AdminApp.update](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_updatingapp.html) in wsadmin.